# joblib and add new row to dataframe

Tags: python

I define the following function to update my date frame

```
def func(idx,value):
    if idx in df.index:
        df.loc[idx] += value
    else:
        df.loc[idx] = value
```

Then, I use joblib for parellel looping

```
Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(delayed(func)(idx, value) for idx, value in key(df2.name,df.score))
```

For instance, I have two dataframe:

```
name    score
john    10
```

and

```
name    score
john    10
chris   20
chris   10
```

Then, I expect my function to update the first dataframe to

```
name    score
john    20
chris   30
```

Then, I get some error saying assignment destination is read-only meaning. I think it happens because I try to add a new row to dataframe while parallel computing.

Is there any way to get around? I am also open to any other suggestions than parallel looping for boosting for loops, maybe gpu computing using cudf (not sure if that speed up for loop).

Answer (score 1):

You could group you dataframe and iterate over the groups, passing each group to the function and storing the results of your function to a list, which you can concatenate at the end.

Here we have some names and ages, we will group by age and pass that a parallel function, taking the mean and returning the results to a list, which is concatenated for the final product.

```
import pandas as pd
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import multiprocessing

df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['john','john','chris','chris'],
                  'age':[23,46,32,56]})

def applyParallel(dfGrouped, func):

    retLst = Parallel(n_jobs=multiprocessing.cpu_count())(delayed(func)(name, data) for name, data in dfGrouped)

    return pd.concat(retLst)


def my_function(name,data):
    ### Process data here
    data = data.groupby('name').mean()
    return data

# Group by some column in your dataframe
output = applyParallel(df.groupby(['name']), my_function)
```

Output

```
         age
name    
chris   44.0
john    34.5
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your code, but it does not give me what I want...
I have added examples of what I want, and if I am mistaken, please explain how your code could help me again? Thank you!